# oracle-adf: Inserting the value of an input box

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm working with Oracle ADF and I can not get a simple feature, practically, the value of an input box (from a binding) must be stored on the database in a table other than the original? How do I go about using the ADF? Do you have ideas, example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe create a separate EO/VO for the other table and simply copy the value from one bound field to another? I assume you have a button to commit changes. The backing bean code could copy the values, or use a setActionListener tied to the button to copy the values.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done both programmatically and using adf-bindings. which one do you want?Be specific on what you ask